GeoDNS with bind
I'm trying to implement a geodns server using bind9. I've created the zones and the work on their own.
when I try to use views It says "when using "view" statement, all zones must be in views"
I tried removing; excluding; all the default zones and I even tried adding all the zones in the views, it still says that.
